# Running FMU generated by Scilab on FMU SDK

Tags: scilab, fmi

I have successfully exported an FMU from Scilab, and I want to simulate it via FMU SDK. But when I run it, it says:

> bin/fmusim_cs:symbol lookup error:PD_Controller.so:undefined symbol: summation

...and the simulation was stopped.

So what should I do now?

Comment: Come up with a more specific question.  Perhaps read the docs for Scilab, and investigate the root of the error that you've received.

Comment: hello! thank you for answering so quick. The whole error was: bin/fmusim_cs: symbol lookup error: fmuTmpa9UWIl/binaries/linux64/PD_Controller.so : undefined symbol: summation.